# Окрасить ячейку таблицы в зависимости от данных ячейки

Tags: java, javafx

Нашел в интернете вроде бы хороший пример как это сделать, по факту - не работает. Ниже представлен код с моими комментариями, помогите пожалуйста разобраться что к чему и почему не работает.

```
 @FXML
    private void initialize() {
// Красим ячейки
        timeContractColumn.setCellFactory(column -> {
            return new TableCell<MainData, LocalDate>() { //MainData - класс model, 
//где хранятся все переменные и коллекции для хранения данных, 
//timeContractColumn - хранит в себе введенную дату, поэтому и LocalDate
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if (item == null || empty) { //Если ячейка пустая
                        setText(null);
                        setStyle("");
                    } else { //Если ячейка не пустая

                        setText(item.toString()); //Помещаем данные в ячейку

                        // Мы получаем здесь всю информацию о этой строки
                        MainData auxPerson = getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex());

                        // Меняем стиль если...
                        if (auxPerson.getTimeContract().equals("2019-04-09")) {
                            setTextFill(Color.RED);
                            setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                        } else {
                            //Здесь мы видим, выделена ли строка этой ячейки или нет
                            if(getTableView().getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems().contains(auxPerson))
                                setTextFill(Color.WHITE);
                            else
                                setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В итоге виновата невнимательность, выходит так что у меня не срабатывало условие `if (auxPerson.getTimeContract().equals("2019-04-09"))`, а не срабатывало оно, т. к. я сравниваю тип данных `LocalDate` с строкой обычной, и если прописать `if (auxPerson.getTimeContract().toString().equals("2019-04-09"))` то все заработает.